# php mysql echo results according to timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, database, timestamp, echo

i have an upload script which takes a timestamp when an advert is uploaded, i want to create a script that will echo the last 10 uploads according to the timestamp.

i have no idea how to do this, any help much appreciated!!

```
<?php

$now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

echo $now;

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE posttime < $now LIMIT 0, 10";

  $q     = $conn->prepare($sql) or die("failed!");
  // Bind the params to the placeholders
   $q->execute();


 ?>
```

the time stamp is as follows:

```
2012-10-05 14:40:21
```

Comment: Also check that the posttime field is of type DATETIME or similar in the database, not just a text type.

Comment: Note that if are using a prepared statement, you should be binding parameters. Instead, you have directly inserted the variable `$now` (which I realize doesn't come from user input), and in any case it should be single-quoted as a DATETIME literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better is use MySQL condition:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE posttime < NOW() LIMIT 0, 10
```

But in your case `posttime` always lower than current, I think :) In this case I think right query is:

```
SELECT * FROM people ORDER BY posttime DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

But if your compare time not always current time, than add condition:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE posttime < $someNotCurrentTimePHPVar ORDER BY posttime DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the `order by` clause

```
SELECT * 
FROM people 
WHERE posttime < $now 
order by posttime desc
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `order by` clause in `desc` order in your query, like this,

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE posttime < $now order by posttime desc LIMIT 0, 10";
```